# Earth Package question on prediction mismatch

Tags: machine-learning

Here is the R code...

```
a <- earth(Volume ~ ., data = trees)
summary(a, digits = 2, style = "pmax")
trees$yhat<-predict(a,newdata=trees[,])
trees$yhat2<-29-3.4 * pmax(0, 14-trees$Girth)+6.2* pmax(0,trees$Girth - 14) + 0.58 * pmax(0, trees$Height - 75)
```

Why is yhat and yhat2 provide different answers? yhat is built-in model prediction and yhat2 is using the mars equation.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using enough significant digits in the formula on 
the last line of your code. Do it like this:

```
library(earth)
a <- earth(Volume ~ ., data = trees)
print(summary(a, style = "pmax", digits=10))
yhat <- predict(a, newdata=trees)
cat("yhat ", yhat, "\n")
yhat2 <- 
    (29.05995351
     - 3.419806152 * pmax(0,         14.2 - trees$Girth)
     + 6.229514342 * pmax(0,  trees$Girth -        14.2)
     + 0.581364384 * pmax(0, trees$Height -          75))
cat("yhat2", yhat2, "\n")
```

which gives (note that `yhat` and `yhat2` now match):

```
...
Volume =
  29.05995351
  - 3.419806152 * pmax(0,   14.2 -  Girth) 
  + 6.229514342 * pmax(0,  Girth -   14.2) 
  + 0.581364384 * pmax(0, Height -     75) 
...

yhat  8.8831 9.909 10.593 16.407 20.579 22.084 ...
yhat2 8.8831 9.909 10.593 16.407 20.579 22.084 ...
```